# About Custom Table in Sun Editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, suneditor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzgZT.png)

I have added a custom table plugin for using different class names and styling.  But when I add a new table to the table first it don't gives an error but just add `<table class="custom-table"><tbody></tbody></table>` without `tr` and `td` in the second time I try it gives this error.

When I try to solve, I realize that x and y are coming undefined. I think there is a problem.

1. I have added
   `'<select class="" id="myClass"  name="option"><option value="se-table-default">Default</option><option value="borderless-table">Border Less</option><option value="inner-borders-table">Inner Borders</option><option value="hide-vertical-lines-table">Hide Vertical Lines</option></select>' +` this to popup and
2. this part
   `let myClass = document.getElementById("myClass"); myClass = myClass.value.replace(/\s/g, "") || "se-table-default"; const oTable = this.util.createElement("TABLE");` to get define class of table.

You can find the codes https://codesandbox.io/s/customtableplugin-xv5v31?file=/src/components/Editor.js here.
How can solve this problem? Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFhwH.png)